# How to update TextField value in a List

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui, textfield

I have a list with `TextField` and a `Button`.

My goal is that I want to provide default value to `TextField` when I toggle the button.

I can do it with `Text`, but I don't know how to do with `TextField`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isEnableBatch: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                isEnableBatch.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(isEnableBatch == true ? "EAIcon-Check_rectangle" : "EAIcon-Check_Box")
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 10, id: \.self) { index in
                    let value = isEnableBatch ? "batch Enable" : "\(index)"
                    Text(value) // <-- I don't know how to do here if i change to textField
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)

        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

If I change to use textField as below

it will show compile error  **No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isEnableBatch: Bool = false
    @State var attValue: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                isEnableBatch.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(isEnableBatch == true ? "EAIcon-Check_rectangle" : "EAIcon-Check_Box")
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 10, id: \.self) { index in
                    attValue = isEnableBatch ? "batch Enable" : "\(index)" <-- how to update TextField's default value ??
                    TextField("", text: $attValue)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)

        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

***Finally, I found how to solve my problems***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isEnableBatch: Bool = false
    @State var attValues: [String] = ["", "" , ""] // <- use an array to store every state value
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                isEnableBatch.toggle()
                // update state value while toggling the button
                if isEnableBatch {
                    for index in 0 ..< 3 {
                        attValues[index] = "batch Enable"
                    }
                } else {
                    for index in 0 ..< 3 {
                        attValues[index] = ""
                    }
                }

            } label: {
                Image(isEnableBatch == true ? "EAIcon-Check_rectangle" : "EAIcon-Check_Box")
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { index in
                    TextField("", text: $attValues[index]) // <-- find the corresponding state value to binding
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)

        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need an editable list and a correct data source, [this article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/building-editable-swiftui-lists/) should be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could update the state variable in the button callback.

In your example, all text fields are sharing the same binding so the prompt is going to be the same for all too:

```swift
Button {
    isEnableBatch.toggle()
    attValue = isEnableBatch ? "batch Enable" : "."

} label: {
    Image(isEnableBatch == true ? "EAIcon-Check_rectangle" : "EAIcon-Check_Box")
}

List {
    ForEach(0 ..< 10, id: \.self) { index in
        TextField("", text: $attValue)
    }
}
```